# Mousemove for mobile

Tags: javascript, slider, addeventlistener, touchmove

I have a website with a splitscreen slider that I want to make mobile friendly. I have an addeventlistener 'mousemove' which allows the slider to go back and forth, but I also want to make it touch activated as well.

I tried replacing the 'mousemove' with 'pointermove' and 'touchmove' but nothing would change. It still won't work on mobile, help please. The [codepen](https://codepen.io/GabriellaFarfan/pen/MEzYjr) shows an example of what I have on my site.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  let topLayer = wrapper.querySelector('.top');
  let handle = wrapper.querySelector('.handle');
  let skew = 0;
  let delta = 0;
  
  if(wrapper.className.indexOf('skewed') != -1){
   skew = 1000;
   }

wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  delta = (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5;
  
  handle.style.left = e.clientX + delta + 'px';
  
  topLayer.style.width= e.clientX + skew + delta + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:55vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer{
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 55vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer .content-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 55vw;
}

.layer .content-body{
  width: 25%;
  position:absolute;
/*   top:50%; */
  top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  color:#fff;
}

.layer img{
  position:absolute;
  width:65%;
/*width: 35%    */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.layer h1 {
  font-size:2em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.bottom{
  background:#686965;
  z-index:1;
}

.bottom .content-body{
  right:5%;
}

.bottom h1{
  color:#7bbe9a;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.top{
  background:#eff0ec;
  color:#222;
  z-index:2;
  width:50vw;
}

.top .content-body{
  left:5%;
  color:#333;
}

.handle{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #7bbe9a;
  width: 5px;
  top:0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index:3;
}

.skewed .handle{
  top:50%;
  transform:rotate(30deg) translateY(-50%);
  height:200%;
  transform-origin:top;
}

.skewed .top{
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  margin-left:-1000px;
  width: calc(50vw + 1000px);
}

.skewed .top .content-wrap{
  transform: skew(30deg);
  margin-left:1000px;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  body{
    font-size:75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Images not Owned by Me -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Nixie+One" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="wrapper" class="skewed">
      <div class="layer bottom">
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <div class="content-body">
            <h1>Designer</h1>
<!--             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> -->
          </div>
          
          <img src="http://3d.ford.com/assets/ford_gt-min.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="layer top">
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <div class="content-body">
            <h1>Developer</h1>
<!--             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> -->
          </div>
          
          <img src="http://3d.ford.com/assets/ford_gt_print.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="handle"></div>
    </section>
    
    <script src=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698441/jquery-ui-draggable-split-screen), in a different post.