# jQuery UI Draggable Split Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, touch, event-listener

I have a split screen slider that works fine on desktop but I needed jQuery UI to make it work on mobile.The draggable event lets me drag it back and forth but sometimes the image on the left moves from it's original position, or disappears altogether. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/GabriellaFarfan/pen/MEzYjr). The slider bug is more visible on mobile devices.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  let topLayer = wrapper.querySelector('.top');
  let handle = wrapper.querySelector('.handle');
  let skew = 0;
  let delta = 0;
  
  if(wrapper.className.indexOf('skewed') != -1){
   skew = 1000;
   }

wrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  delta = (e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5;
  
  handle.style.left = e.clientX + delta + 'px';
  
  topLayer.style.width= e.clientX + skew + delta + 'px';
  });
});

$(".content-wrap").draggable({
  containment: "parent",
  dragx: true,
  dragy: false,
  rotate: false
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:55vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer{
  position:absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 55vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.layer .content-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  width:100vw;
  min-height: 55vw;
}

.layer .content-body{
  width: 25%;
  position:absolute;
/*   top:50%; */
  top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  color:#fff;
}

.layer img{
  position:absolute;
  width:65%;
/*width: 35%    */
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.layer h1 {
  font-size:2em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.bottom{
  background:#686965;
  z-index:1;
}

.bottom .content-body{
  right:5%;
}

.bottom h1{
  color:#7bbe9a;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.top{
  background:#eff0ec;
  color:#222;
  z-index:2;
  width:50vw;
}

.top .content-body{
  left:5%;
  color:#333;
}

.handle{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #7bbe9a;
  width: 5px;
  top:0;
  left: 50%;
  z-index:3;
}

.skewed .handle{
  top:50%;
  transform:rotate(30deg) translateY(-50%);
  height:200%;
  transform-origin:top;
}

.skewed .top{
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  margin-left:-1000px;
  width: calc(50vw + 1000px);
}

.skewed .top .content-wrap{
  transform: skew(30deg);
  margin-left:1000px;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  body{
    font-size:75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<!-- Images not Owned by Me -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Nixie+One" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="wrapper" class="skewed">
<!--       <div id="draggable"> -->
          <div class="layer bottom">
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <div class="content-body">
            <h1>Designer</h1>
<!--             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> -->
          </div>
          
          <img src="http://3d.ford.com/assets/ford_gt-min.png" alt="">
        </div>
      
<!--         </div> -->
       </div>
      
      <div class="layer top">
        <div class="content-wrap">
          <div class="content-body">
            <h1>Developer</h1>
<!--             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> -->
          </div>
          
          <img src="http://3d.ford.com/assets/ford_gt_print.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="handle"></div>
    </section>
    
    <script src=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget the `draggable` as it is causing conflict with the `mousemove` event listener. I have used the `touchmove` event listener for mobile device.
[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/eVvpGq)

```
wrapper.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  delta = (e.changedTouches[0].clientX - window.innerWidth / 2) * 0.5;
  handle.style.left = e.changedTouches[0].clientX + delta + "px";
  topLayer.style.width = e.changedTouches[0].clientX + skew + delta + "px";
});
```

Note: You may also **enable**/**disable** the `touchmove` and `mousemove` depending on the device type (touch or not).

Hope this helps.